# model a entity relationship n:m

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

I have an entity or entities "subject" that can be related to several entities "subject" to make an equivalence between colleges in this way:

Example 1:
Subject1, subject2    <-----------------> SubjectA,SubjectB,SubjectC

Example 2:
Subject1  <--------->   SubjectB, SubjectC

Example 3:
Subject3,Subject1   <--------->  SubjectA

it´s a complete combination of subjects and a valid equivalence must have all required subjects .I think it is a n:m relationship but i don't know how to model this in tables.

First aproach i do this:

Subject:IdSubject,... another fields.

Subject_relation:idsubject_a,idsubject_b,idrelation

Equivalence:Idequivalence,idrelation

But the table subject_relation looks like something like (for example 2)

```
id_relation      idsubject_a        idsubject_b
```

`1           subject1          SubjectB

      1           subject1          SubjectC`

is it fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that you need to model the concept of a `subject_group`. I.E. a group of subjects.

```
subject
-------
PK idsubject int

subject_group
-------------
PK idsubject_group int

subject_group_member
--------------------
PK, FK idsubject_group int
PK, FK idsubject int
```

(You could add a separate primary key for subject_group_member and make the two columns a unique constraint instead, matter of taste and other modelling considerations)

With these tables then you can model equivalence between subject groups fairly easily:

```
subject_group_equivalence
-------------------------
PK idsubject_group_equivalance int
FK idsubject_group_a int
FK idsubject_group_b int
UQ (idsubject_group_a, idsubject_group_b)
```

This is the basic model. It sounds like there may be more complexities in what you actually want. For example, I think you may want subject groups to be restricted to those offered by a single college.